# I can't seem to get my html button tag to work?

Tags: html, css, button, onclick, tags

To cut a long story short I'm trying to make a green bar move upwards over a blue bar when a button is clicked (although I haven't added any JS yet. For some reason no matter what I try my button will not work. I have tried the button tag and the input tag to make the button and it makes no difference. My code currently stands at this:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#container{
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    background-color: brown;
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 75px; 
}
#fullLoad{
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
    left: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
#loader{
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    top: 600px;


}
#btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 362px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: gold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #424242;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id="fullLoad">

        <div id="loader"></div>

    </div>

    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Go !" onclick="alert('Hello')">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't click on the button because the fullLoad and loader divs are placed in front of its parent element (the container div) with a z-index of 1 and 2. The button inherits the default z-index of the container div, which puts it also in the back of the stack order.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Go !" onclick="alert('Hello')">
```

With this

```
<button type=“button” onClick=“alert(‘Hallo’)”>Go!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your negative `z-index` on `#container` is putting the button behind the body, preventing it to be clicked, removing the `z-index` solves this (or increasing the `z-index` from `#container` and `#fullLoad` by 1, if you need in the future):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#container{
    position: relative;
    background-color: brown;
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 75px; 
}
#fullLoad{
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
    left: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
#loader{
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    top: 600px;


}
#btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 362px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: gold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #424242;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id="fullLoad">

        <div id="loader"></div>

    </div>
    
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Go !" onclick="alert('Hello')">

</div>
```